# Sorry, try again: openssl genrsa password on MacOS is not accepted, error is thrown, why?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I want to set up `https` on my localhost.

I'm trying to generate a self signed key and certificate in terminal on MacOS. But password is not accepted.

Why? How to fix or how to avoid password completely?

I tried these passwords, no luck. So numbers and numbers with letters are not accepted:

`1234567890`

`123asd456`

```
$ sudo openssl genrsa -out ~/.localhost-ssl/localhost.key 2048
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Comment: This is coming from sudo not openssl. It's asking for the password for your user account. Do you really need to run this as root?

Comment: @MattCaswell You are so right. Indeed from `sudo`. Not sure if I need `sudo`, I'm following an instruction on how to set up https for localhost.

Comment: Whether you need it or not depends on whether your user account has permissions to write the key to the location you are trying to write it to.

Comment: Then I do not need it. I'm doing all these scripts in my home directory.